# Soccer parabolic trajectory problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

I'm in my first college year and we've been given some HS style Physics problems to refresh our knowledge. There is one of the problems which I'm almost sure lacks necessary information.

> A soccer player kicks a penalty ball forming an angle of 25° with the horizontal, and with a velocity of 40 m/s. The goalie jumps forward one meter, and hits the ball with a force F = (-9N, 8N/seg-1/2N). His contact with the ball lasts 0,1 seconds. Find how much does the ball move during the contact with the goalie, and answer if it does enter the goal or not. Also, which was the ball's height when the goalie first touches it?

We are supposed to use Calculus tools here, which I did for another problems successfully. Here, however, I just cant see how it could be solved without the height of the goalie ans the mass of the ball. I could find the acceleration caused by the contact with the keeper with the force components, dividing by mass. But we haven't mass!

Is there anything that I'm missing here, or does it truly lack necessary data?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Thanks for your orientation! I think I only need a general orientation here, mainly about if the problem really has some kind of mistake in its wording or it can be solved with the provided data.

Comment: The setting suggests that regulation dimensions and mass of soccer ball should be used. Perhaps you are expected to use your initiative to find this information, and to estimate the height of the goalie. Perhaps the height of the goalie is not required, it being assumed that contact is made with the ball 1m from the goal line.

Comment: What is  F = (-9N, 8N/seg-1/2N) ?  What's that seg-1/2 thing?

Comment: @puppetsock We are given the X and Y components of the force exerted by the goalkeeper; we must divide it by the object's mass, get X and Y acceleration, integrate, get velocity, etc. Deliberately messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh heh. Maybe you are supposed to be a soccer wiz with all of this information in your brain. Is it a college in England? Heh. You could go outside and measure.

When there is missing information you need to assume.  So:

Assume it is all in a straight line that is perpendicular to the goal line. It gets mighty messy if you allow the shot to be at any angle to the goal line. Though you could include this side-ways angle as an additional parameter. Then you would need to look up the width of the goal and determine the permitted angles.

The ball starts at the level of the field.

The ball starts at the penalty kick spot.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_area

The keeper will start at the goal line and move 1 m forward. You now have the x-y coords of the start of the ball's parabola. And you have the angle, and the speed. And you have the x-coord when the keeper contacts it. You can work out the y-coord at contact.

A standard soccer ball has a specified weight range. Pick the middle of the range.

https://www.livestrong.com/article/418901-what-is-the-weight-of-a-size-5-soccer-ball/

Now you can estimate the impulse during contact. That will give you a new velocity starting at the contact point. That should allow you to estimate if it will enter the goal. Maybe you will have to look up how high a ball is permitted to rise and still be counted as in the goal. Or maybe it won't matter.

After all that you should pin your answer to a sweaty soccer jersey, and hand that in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems the most logical way: just "assume" a lot of things, or maybe know them! No, it's not from England but from Argentina. I'm here on an exchange program and I can see they do teach some things in a different way!